# How to optimize matching a substring of n length, but only whole words?

Tags: python, regex, string

We need to display some "preview text" from a larger string that can be, at most, 'n' characters long.  Unfortunately, I couldn't find an existing module on PyPi that handles this.

I'm hoping to do a proper solution.  While my quick & dirty solution below works, it's not that efficient -- lots of constant comparisons.  Does anyone have an idea on how to improve?  I tried a regex, but gave up after 20 minutes.

The kludgy solution I came up with is good enough for most needs, I just know this could be done faster and more concisely - and I'd love to know how.

```
sample = "This is a sample string and I would like to break it down by words, without exceeding max_chars."

def clean_cut( text , max_chars ):
    rval = []
    words = text.split(' ')
    for word in words:
        len_rval = len(' '.join(rval))
        if len_rval + 1 + len(word) > max_chars :
            break
        rval.append(word)
    return ' '.join(rval)

for i in ( 15, 16, 17,30,35):
    cutdown = clean_cut( sample , i )
    print "%s | %s" % ( i , cutdown )
```

and output is right...

```
15 | This is a
16 | This is a sample
17 | This is a sample
30 | This is a sample string and I
35 | This is a sample string and I would
```

Comment: How about just scanning through the string, and use a marker to mark the last position that can be cut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following implementation may work for you

```
def clean_cut(st, end):
    st += ' ' #In case end > len(st)
    return st[:st[:end + 1].rfind(' ')]
for i in ( 15, 16, 17,30,35):
    cutdown = clean_cut( sample , i )
    print "%s | %s" % ( i , cutdown )
```

Output

```
15 | This is a
16 | This is a sample
17 | This is a sample
30 | This is a sample string and I
35 | This is a sample string and I would
```

---

**Note**

Compared to textwrap, this implementation is 50 times faster

```
>>> stmt_ab = """
for i in ( 15, 16, 17,30,35):
    cutdown = sample[:sample[:i + 1].rfind(' ')]
"""
>>> stmt_mg = """
for i in ( 15, 16, 17,30,35):
    cutdown =  textwrap.wrap(sample[:i+1],i)[0]
"""
>>> import timeit
>>> t1_ab = timeit.Timer(stmt=stmt_ab, setup = "from __main__ import sample")
>>> t1_mg = timeit.Timer(stmt=stmt_mg, setup = "from __main__ import sample, textwrap")
>>> t1_ab.timeit(10000)
0.10367805429780219
>>> t1_mg.timeit(10000)
5.597085870104877
>>>
```

Comment: Oh bother!  foiled again :) -- but I bet you had to think (slightly) harder than I did :).  Of course, for really short 1-word strings, I believe this answer print too much ... `cutdown = sample[:sample[:3 + 1].rfind(' ')]`, probably not an issue, but worth mentioning at least.

Comment: @mgilson:  `Of course, for really short 1-word strings, I believe this answer will cut off the last character` .. good catch and aptly corrected now. Actually I started with a completely different complex generator based implementation but somehow ended up here :-)

Comment: sorry, i forgot to say a huge THANK YOU yesterday. this is a brilliant approach.  and really damn fast.

Answer (score 1):

```
def substring_match(length, string):
    return re.search('(.{1,%d}) ' % length, string).group(0).strip()
```

Should work, did for my trivial tests

Comment: If the string is short and does not end in space, your way will end up not taking all the text.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `textwrap`:

```
textwrap.wrap(yourstring[:length+1],length)[0]
```

Slicing the string isn't particularly necessary but will probably make the whole thing a bit more efficient...

```
>>> textwrap.wrap(sample[:15+1],15)[0]
'This is a'
>>> textwrap.wrap(sample[:16+1],16)[0]
'This is a sample'
>>> textwrap.wrap(sample[:17+1],17)[0]
'This is a sample'
>>> textwrap.wrap(sample[:30+1],30)[0]
'This is a sample string and I'
>>> textwrap.wrap(sample[:35+1],35)[0]
'This is a sample string and I would'
```

Comment: i never thought of looking in the standard library!

Comment: It has so much useful stuff in there :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are good library function to do the job for you, like `textwrap` as pointer out by @mgilson's answer.

I'll add a regex answer just for fun:

```
^.{0,n}(?<=\S)(?!\S)
```

Replace n with the limit, and use this regex to search for first match (there is only 1 match maximum). I consider any non-space character being part of a word. The positive look-behind makes sure the last character of the match is non-space, and the negative look-ahead makes sure the character after the last character in the match is a space character or end of string.

In case you want to match something when the string starts with a long sequence of non-space, this regex will just break the sequence of non-space characters at the character limit:

```
^.{0,n}(?<=\S)(?!\S)|^\S{n}
```